# Postgresql - Return (N) rows for each ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

```
contact_id |  phone_number 
         1 |  55551002
         1 |  55551003
         1 |  55551000
         2 |  55552001
         2 |  55552008
         2 |  55552003
         2 |  55552007
         3 |  55553001
         3 |  55553002
         3 |  55553009
         3 |  55553004
         4 |  55554000
```

I want to return only 3 numbers of each contact_id, order by phone_number, like this:

```
contact_id | phone_number
         1 |  55551000
         1 |  55551002
         1 |  55551003
         2 |  55552001
         2 |  55552003
         2 |  55552007
         3 |  55553001
         3 |  55553002
         3 |  55553004
         4 |  55554000
```

please need be an optimized query.

My Query

```
SELECT a.cod_cliente, count(a.telefone) as qtd
FROM crm.contatos a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM crm.contatos b
    LIMIT 3
  ) AS sub_contatos ON sub_contatos.cod_contato = a.cod_cliente
group by a.cod_cliente;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of query can easily be solved using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select contact_id, phone_number
from (
  select contact_id, phone_number, 
         row_Number() over (partition by contact_id order by phone_number) as rn
  from crm.contatos
) t
where rn <= 3
order by contact_id, phone_number;
```